# How can i make a button, that resets the android app to onCreate(inside the app)?

Tags: android, button, reset, oncreate

I tried to use this code to reset my app.
But this idea switches out resets it and goes back in.

Looking for a solution, where my input data is gone and back to the oncreate version.
Without any crazy animation.

```
if (v == buttonReset)
{
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
.getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Basically what this does is get the intent in which this activity has started start it with that intent and finally stop it.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

OR even this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Hope this helps!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thx, this is working better then my solution.
This time it doesnt jump  out the app and goes back to the mainActivity.class.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your activity sounds - unforunately - like a poor functional design. I don't recommend to recreate the whole activity, but make a method `init()` that you call in `onCreate()`. At the moment you would like to 'reset' the activity, call `init()` again.

Comment: i see what you mean.
try to this your way, so it jump back to the top of line.